# How do I deploy MongoDB app on Heroku and connect it to MongoDB Atlas?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express

More precisely, which URI do I use in the mongoose connect method when deploying my app to Heroku and how do I connect it to MongoDB Atlas?

Currently my code looks like this and it works well on my local server:

```
mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost:27017/facebook')
```

After deploying on Heroku and on trying to access the app, I get an application error.
I ran the heroku logs --tail command and I get the following error:

```
2022-02-16T04:22:16.055858+00:00 app[web.1]: _hostAddress: HostAddress { isIPv6: false, host: 'localhost', port: 27017 },
2022-02-16T04:22:16.055858+00:00 app[web.1]: address: 'localhost:27017',
2022-02-16T04:22:16.055858+00:00 app[web.1]: type: 'Unknown',
2022-02-16T04:22:16.055859+00:00 app[web.1]: hosts: [],
2022-02-16T04:22:16.055859+00:00 app[web.1]: passives: [],
2022-02-16T04:22:16.055860+00:00 app[web.1]: arbiters: [],
2022-02-16T04:22:16.055860+00:00 app[web.1]: tags: {},
2022-02-16T04:22:16.055860+00:00 app[web.1]: minWireVersion: 0,
2022-02-16T04:22:16.055861+00:00 app[web.1]: maxWireVersion: 0,
2022-02-16T04:22:16.055861+00:00 app[web.1]: roundTripTime: -1,
2022-02-16T04:22:16.055861+00:00 app[web.1]: lastUpdateTime: 570484147,
2022-02-16T04:22:16.055862+00:00 app[web.1]: lastWriteDate: 0,
2022-02-16T04:22:16.055862+00:00 app[web.1]: error: MongoNetworkError: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:27017
2022-02-16T04:22:16.055862+00:00 app[web.1]: at connectionFailureError (/app/node_modules/mongodb/lib/cmap/connect.js:381:20)
2022-02-16T04:22:16.055863+00:00 app[web.1]: at Socket.<anonymous> (/app/node_modules/mongodb/lib/cmap/connect.js:301:22)
2022-02-16T04:22:16.055863+00:00 app[web.1]: at Object.onceWrapper (node:events:640:26)
2022-02-16T04:22:16.055863+00:00 app[web.1]: at Socket.emit (node:events:520:28)
2022-02-16T04:22:16.055864+00:00 app[web.1]: at emitErrorNT (node:internal/streams/destroy:157:8)
2022-02-16T04:22:16.055864+00:00 app[web.1]: at emitErrorCloseNT (node:internal/streams/destroy:122:3)
2022-02-16T04:22:16.055864+00:00 app[web.1]: at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:83:21)
2022-02-16T04:22:16.055864+00:00 app[web.1]: }
2022-02-16T04:22:16.055865+00:00 app[web.1]: },
2022-02-16T04:22:16.055865+00:00 app[web.1]: stale: false,
2022-02-16T04:22:16.055865+00:00 app[web.1]: compatible: true,
2022-02-16T04:22:16.055865+00:00 app[web.1]: heartbeatFrequencyMS: 10000,
2022-02-16T04:22:16.055865+00:00 app[web.1]: localThresholdMS: 15,
2022-02-16T04:22:16.055866+00:00 app[web.1]: logicalSessionTimeoutMinutes: undefined
2022-02-16T04:22:16.055866+00:00 app[web.1]: }
```

What can I do to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

This URL ***'mongodb://localhost:27017/facebook'*** should only be used when you have a MongoDB server running on the same server as the app, as you can see there **localhost** is in the URL string, it throws an error because it can't find any running MongoDB database on the server which your app is running on Heroku

And to connect it with MongoDB atlas is quite easy, just go ahead create an account and a cluster [mongodb doc](https://docs.atlas.mongodb.com/tutorial/create-new-cluster/), in there you will find your cluster URl. Replace this current URL with it and you should be good.

And Yes I skipped some part about whitelisting IP addresses and user permission, but MongoDB atlas should prompt you to do so